# meaning of "giddy-up"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, slang, idiom-meaning

I'm reading The Sellout by Paul Beatty. It says:

"All I know is that I’m pre-black. Dickens born and raised. Homo sapiens OG Crip from the goddamn
primordial **giddy-up**, nigger."

What does "giddy-up" mean here?
I know it means "go faster", but it doesn't make sense here.

Answer (score 8):

Since ***giddy-up*** commands a horse to get moving, it can be used to mean ***from the start***. A similar phrase would be ***[from the get-go](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/from%20the%20get-go)***, which M/W has as "from the very beginning". **Primordial** then is an intensifier, "from the really very beginning, way back when."

Comment: Nice. And I would ascribe giddy-up to *Getting up* or even *Get ye up*.

Comment: And it is slightly rhyming and adhering to the referenced concept: "The Primordial **Soup**" - which was the bath of chemicals in the oceans of the early earth that created conditions for life to emerge. All the metaphors add up to that the author establishes authority because of a lineage to the original thing. Undiluted and pure, basically. I find it interesting to reference purity as authority so laden with profanity. Applause.

Answer (score 1):

A little more context would help but I understand this dense and effective prose to refer to the goddamn (=disgusting and deplorable) primordial (=original) brutal reality of black slavery, to the reduction of human relationship to the coarse master-slave ordering to giddy-up (=hurry-up with the work, with progress; *giddy-up* being a demeaning order usually given to horses). Such barbarous inhumanity both characterised and defined the status of black people in those days.

The phrase “goddamn primordial giddy-up” is thus an adjectival noun phrase, modifying “homo sapiens”, which is finally equated to “nigger” by the separating comma, which puts the modified “homo sapiens” and “nigger” into apposition.

This interpretation fits with the narrator’s additional modification of “homo sapiens” towards the final appositional “nigger” by his mentions of “pre-black” (=already defined as black), to rural life in the fictional Dickens agrarian suburb, and to the OG (=authentic) membership of the Crips gangs (black-influenced Los Angeles gangs).

Comment: "Nigger" here is a direct address, not an appositive.

Comment: @GArthurBrown I am grateful for the stimulus to look at this again. I should have attributed the apposition of nigger to “homo sapiens” (as modified by the following text). My answer is altered accordingly.

Comment: "Nigger" is a common form of address in many communities. There is no apposition because the speaker is telling someone whom he refers to as "nigger" about qualities that apply to the speaker himself.